# Count total number of pixels for each color

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am trying to calculate the number of pixels corresponding to each of the color for the segmented image

[image]

Following is the code that I have written.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import argparse
from ast import literal_eval

try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
except ImportError:
    exit("This script requires the PIL module. Install with pip install Pillow")

try:
    import webcolors
except ImportError:

    exit("This script uses webcolors for displaying named colors. Install with pip install webcolors")

def count_pixels(filename):
    """
    Returns a count of pixels per a unique color
    Args:
        filename (str): the image to count the number of pixels of
    Returns:
        a key-value pairing of the rgb color value and the number of times the color was present in the image
    """
    color_count = {}
    with Image.open(filename) as image:
        width, height = image.size
        rgb_image = image.convert('RGB')

        # iterate through each pixel in the image and keep a count per unique color
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                rgb = rgb_image.getpixel((x, y))

                if rgb in color_count:
                    color_count[rgb] += 1
                else:
                    color_count[rgb] = 1

    return color_count

def create_legend_image(filename, colors, title, ignore_color):
    """
    Create an image of color swatches paired with a color name and number
    Args:
        filename (str): the name of the legend image file
        colors (dict): a key-value pairing of the color name and count
        title (str): a title for the legend image
        ignore_color (tuple): do not add this color to the legend image
    Returns:
        None
    """
    margin = 10
    rect_width = 25
    rect_outline_width = 2
    font_size = 20
    img_width = 250
    img_height = len(colors) * (rect_width + rect_outline_width + margin) + (0 if title is None else font_size)
    legend_img = Image.new("RGBA", (img_width, img_height), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(legend_img)    
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", font_size)
    
    # draw title for legend if applicable
    text_height = 0
    if title is not None:
        _, text_height = draw.textsize(title, font=font)
        draw.text((0, 0), title, font=font, fill="black")

    color_index = 1
    for color, count in colors.items():
        if color == ignore_color:
            continue

        try:
            # convert RGB color to a human readable color if applicable
            color_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(color)
        except ValueError:                
            color_name = color

        # draw square for color legend
        y0 = rect_width * (color_index - 1) + margin * color_index + text_height
        y1 = rect_width * color_index + margin * color_index + text_height
        draw.rectangle([(0, y0), (rect_width, y1)], fill=color, outline="black", width=2)

        # draw color name next and pixel count for legend colors
        draw.text((rect_width + margin, y0), "{}: {}".format(color_name, count), font=font, fill="black")

        color_index += 1

    legend_img.save(filename, mode="w")

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Calculates the sum of pixels per a color')
    parser.add_argument('image', nargs='?', default='.', help='The image to sum the pixels per a color of')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--ignore-color', help='Skip counting pixels of this color')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--title', help='Title for the image legend')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--legend-image', help='Generate an image with color swatches paired with the pixel count')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    ignore_color = literal_eval(args.ignore_color) if args.ignore_color is not None else None
    color_count = count_pixels(args.image)                   

    if args.legend_image is not None:
        create_legend_image(args.legend_image, color_count, args.title, ignore_color)
 
    # outputs pixel color count to console
    print('Pixel Count per Unique Color:')
    print('-' * 30)
    color_index = 1

    for color, count in color_count.items(): 
        if color == ignore_color:
            continue

        try:
            # convert RGB color to a human readable color if applicable
            color_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(color)
        except ValueError:                
            color_name = color

        print('{}.) {}: {}'.format(color_index, color_name, count))

        color_index += 1

    # Display the total number of pixels not ignored
    print('-' * 30)
    print('\t{} pixels'.format(sum(color_count[color] for color in color_count if color != ignore_color)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I test my code, I am not getting the accurate result which indicates total number of pixels for each of the unique colors represented in the picture i.e. (Red, Yellow and Black), Can you suggest me some alternative approach to calculate the total number of pixels in a segmented image

Comment: `np.histogram`?

Comment: @QuangHoang , I have tried that before but i could not get accurate result, you can test using  np.histogram on my image and you will get a strange error, it shows several colors in an image although i can only see 3 colors and small white pixel

Comment: Your eyes might not be able to detect similar colors, e.g. `(100, 100, 100)` and `(100, 100, 99)`. You might want to do histogram with bins...

Comment: You really shouldn't store segmented, or labelled, or classified images as JPEG. It is a **LOSSY** format that changes pixels. Your posted image has nearly 7,000 unique colours. Do you have a proper, lossless PNG?

Comment: @MarkSetchell ,  I have a .png image, i will post it now

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I have changed my image , can you check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest way to get the colours and their corresponding counts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image and ensure RGB
im = Image.open('UMN9c.png').convert('RGB')

# Make into Numpy array
na = np.array(im)

# Get colours and corresponding counts
colours, counts = np.unique(na.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)

print(colours, counts)
```

**Sample Outputs**

```
 [[ 37  36  36]
 [226  44  11]
 [228 239  80]] [255169   1059   5916]
```

---

If you don't want to write any Python code, you can just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal

```
magick -verbose UMN9c.png -format %c histogram:info:-
```

**Output**

```
UMN9c.png PNG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3572B 0.020u 0:00.008
255169: (37,36,36,255) #252424FF srgba(37,36,36,1)
1059: (226,44,11,255) #E22C0BFF srgba(226,44,11,1)
5916: (228,239,80,255) #E4EF50FF srgba(228,239,80,1)
UMN9c.png=>info:- PNG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3572B 0.320u 0:00.166
```

---

I'm not sure if outright speed is an issue for you. If so, there is a significantly faster method using `np.dot()` at the end of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59671950/2836621) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Solution using OpenCV for import.

```
# Load image
img = cv2.imread("UMN9c.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Flatten image into rows = number of pixels, columns = 3 (RGB)
img = img.reshape(-1, img.shape[2])

# Count number of unique colors
unique_colors, unique_count = np.unique(img, axis=0, return_counts=True)

# Print info
print(unique_colors)
print(unique_count)
print("Total number of unique colors: ", unique_colors.shape[0])
```